# Forward push notification and calls notification to ble device

Tags: android, ios, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, forward

I'm trying to understand how even the chinese smartwatches retrives the notifications that I receive on my iPhone, even without any dedicated app installed, all via bluetooth.

My goal is to use a BLE module (like an esp32 or so), connect it to my iPhone like if it is a smartwatch, and receive something on BLE when I receive a notification on my phone.

How it works, or how this "function" is called, so I can do I research online.. at the moment I did not find anything.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I will take a detail look, but it seems a good start :D